# React-Native app build on mobile.azure.com with error

Tags: azure, react-native, build

I'm trying to configure a signed build on mobile.azure.com but, even if I managed to generate the 2 files needed, my build is failing with the following error:

```
CompileC /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VisitorsManager.build/Release-iphoneos/VisitorsManager.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.o VisitorsManager/AppDelegate.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/vsts/agent/2.127.0/work/1/s/ios
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode_9.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode_9.2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/vsts/bin:/Users/vsts/.yarn/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode_9.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch arm64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wno-non-literal-null-conversion -Wno-objc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode_9.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-infinite-recursion -Wno-comma -Wno-block-capture-autoreleasing -Wno-strict-prototypes -fembed-bitcode -iquote /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VisitorsManager.build/Release-iphoneos/VisitorsManager.build/VisitorsManager-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VisitorsManager.build/Release-iphoneos/VisitorsManager.build/VisitorsManager-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VisitorsManager.build/Release-iphoneos/VisitorsManager.build/VisitorsManager-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VisitorsManager.build/Release-iphoneos/VisitorsManager.build/VisitorsManager-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/include -I/Users/vsts/agent/2.127.0/work/1/s/ios/../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager -I../node_modules/react-native-signature-capture/ios -I/Users/vsts/agent/2.127.0/work/1/s/ios/../node_modules/react-native-view-shot/ios -I../node_modules/react-native-camera/ios -I../node_modules/react-native-fetch-blob/ios -I../node_modules/react-native-fetch-blob/ios/RNFetchBlob -I/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VisitorsManager.build/Release-iphoneos/VisitorsManager.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -I/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VisitorsManager.build/Release-iphoneos/VisitorsManager.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VisitorsManager.build/Release-iphoneos/VisitorsManager.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VisitorsManager.build/Release-iphoneos/VisitorsManager.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.dia -c /Users/vsts/agent/2.127.0/work/1/s/ios/VisitorsManager/AppDelegate.m -o /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VisitorsManager.build/Release-iphoneos/VisitorsManager.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.o
/Users/vsts/agent/2.127.0/work/1/s/ios/VisitorsManager/AppDelegate.m:11:9: fatal error: 'AppCenterReactNativeCrashes/AppCenterReactNativeCrashes.h' file not found
#import <AppCenterReactNativeCrashes/AppCenterReactNativeCrashes.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

CompileC /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VisitorsManager.build/Release-iphoneos/VisitorsManager.build/Objects-normal/arm64/main.o VisitorsManager/main.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/vsts/agent/2.127.0/work/1/s/ios
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode_9.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode_9.2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/vsts/bin:/Users/vsts/.yarn/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/vsts/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode_9.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch arm64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -Os -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wno-non-literal-null-conversion -Wno-objc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode_9.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -g -fvisibility=hidden -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-infinite-recursion -Wno-comma -Wno-block-capture-autoreleasing -Wno-strict-prototypes -fembed-bitcode -iquote /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VisitorsManager.build/Release-iphoneos/VisitorsManager.build/VisitorsManager-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VisitorsManager.build/Release-iphoneos/VisitorsManager.build/VisitorsManager-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VisitorsManager.build/Release-iphoneos/VisitorsManager.build/VisitorsManager-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VisitorsManager.build/Release-iphoneos/VisitorsManager.build/VisitorsManager-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/include -I/Users/vsts/agent/2.127.0/work/1/s/ios/../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager -I../node_modules/react-native-signature-capture/ios -I/Users/vsts/agent/2.127.0/work/1/s/ios/../node_modules/react-native-view-shot/ios -I../node_modules/react-native-camera/ios -I../node_modules/react-native-fetch-blob/ios -I../node_modules/react-native-fetch-blob/ios/RNFetchBlob -I/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VisitorsManager.build/Release-iphoneos/VisitorsManager.build/DerivedSources/arm64 -I/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VisitorsManager.build/Release-iphoneos/VisitorsManager.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VisitorsManager.build/Release-iphoneos/VisitorsManager.build/Objects-normal/arm64/main.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VisitorsManager.build/Release-iphoneos/VisitorsManager.build/Objects-normal/arm64/main.dia -c /Users/vsts/agent/2.127.0/work/1/s/ios/VisitorsManager/main.m -o /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VisitorsManager.build/Release-iphoneos/VisitorsManager.build/Objects-normal/arm64/main.o

** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/vsts/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VisitorsManager-fpaaihpodppqzjbcxwmcmpicquwb/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/VisitorsManager/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/VisitorsManager.build/Release-iphoneos/VisitorsManager.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.o VisitorsManager/AppDelegate.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
##[section]Finishing: Xcode build (not signed)
##[section]Starting: Analyze build log
```

I also followed this great example on youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cI-978DHaA

Appreciate any suggestion.